# SlideToggle gets blocked by debounce

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I have a submenu that I want to scroll.
There is a function that needs to be debounce, otherwise everything 
lags. For some reason the debounce function is blocking the slideToggle
that needs to respond instantly. Is the setTimeOut on the debounce causing this?
I tried the jquery off function on the scroll and debounce but is not working. 
Here is the scroll submenu piece of code:

```
function sidebarFollow() {
        ...

            var boldHeaderLinks = function() {
                    ...
                }
                //header links take to long to calculate we need to debounce
               $(window).scroll(debounce(boldHeaderLinks, 300, false));
            }
```

And here is the debounce from [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };
```

On click I want to be able to toggle the submenu:

```
   $(".submenu-btn").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $self = $(this),
      submenu = $(this).attr("href");
      $self.toggleClass("active");
      $(submenu).slideToggle(250, function() {
        // only run if there's a sidebar on the page
        if ($(".panel-left").length) {
            // adjust sidebar after sidebar height has changed
            hasSlideToggle = true;
            sidebarFollow();
            hasSlideToggle = false;
        }
    });
});
```